# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: createCriteria grails

Tags: mongodb, grails, createcriteria

I'm getting the `NoSuchMethodError` on `createCriteria` method in Grails. I don't know somehow it is not recognizing the method. I have the `createCriteria` in other projects, but it is not working here.

```
Domain.where {  }
```

Above is also not working. Here is my code:

```
def res = Employee.createCriteria().list {
    or {
        eq('validOn',date)
        eq('day',day)
    }
}
println "res"+res
```

I'm getting this error:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: in.aoo.EmployeeController$_chefPackaging_closure12.<init>(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lgroovy/lang/Reference;Lgroovy/lang/Reference;)
```

Comment: Is Grails recognizing Employee as a domain class? You can check by running `grailsApplication.allArtefacts`

Answer (score 0):

There can be a few possibilities of this error. The first and most common is that the `Employee` class is not located under `grails-app/domain` directory instead located under the `src/groovy` package.

The second can be that your classpath can have two `Employee` class in different packages. One must be your domain and another is simple Java or Groovy class. So you must have imported with the wrong package.

Comment: thanks, but here none is the case , any other cause for this ??

Comment: Can you reproduce it to a new fresh app and push it to GitHub?